Рвется соединение с сетевой папкой, установленное через sshfs, при разрыве сессии ssh
Astra Linux
Примонтировал сетевую папку через sshfs на сервере, если закрыть сессию с этим сервером, после возвращения на него, папки примонтированной нет, проверял командой df -h.
Строка в файле /etc/fstab:
user@ip:/data /mnt/60data fuse.sshfs noauto,x-systemd.automount,_netdev,reconnect,identityfile=/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa,allow_other,default_permissions 0 0

Что я делаю не так?, может есть какие то параметры особенные,

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.
